# Nice way to transfer to namedtuple

Tags: python, collections, namedtuple

I'm writing a function, that translates tuple or a pair of arguments to a namedtuple with int fields.

```
from collections import namedtuple

EPS = 0.00000001

def point(*cont: 'tuple or pair of args') -> namedtuple('Point', 'x y'):
    """Make an int named pair (Point)"""
    if len(cont) == 1:
        res = namedtuple('Point', 'x y')
        if abs(int(cont[0][0])-cont[0][0]) < EPS:
            res.x = int(cont[0][0])
        else:
            res.x = cont[0][0]
        if abs(int(cont[0][1])-cont[0][1]) < EPS:
            res.y = int(cont[0][1])
        else:
            res.y = cont[0][1]
    else:
        res = namedtuple('Point', 'x y')
        if abs(int(cont[0])-cont[0]) < EPS:
            res.x = int(cont[0])
        else:
            res.x = cont[0]
        if abs(int(cont[1])-cont[1]) < EPS:
            res.y = int(cont[1])
        else:
            res.y = cont[1]
    return res
```

Is there a nicer way to do that?

Comment: Welcome to SO please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.  If you have a working solution and want a critique, post over at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

One major flaw with your code is that it's not actually *using* `namedtuple`, you're just setting attributes on the `namedtuple` class. Your code would not behave any differently if you were to replace `namedtuple('Point', 'x y')` with any other object that allows you to add attributes:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x y')
>>> Point.x = 5
>>> Point.y = 5
>>> Point.z = 5  # uh oh
>>> Point
<class '__main__.Point'>
>>> point = Point(1, 2)  # how it should work
>>> point
Point(x=1, y=2)
>>> isinstance(Point, tuple)
False
>>> isinstance(point, tuple)
True
```

Once you fix that, here's how I'd simplify your code a little:

```
Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x y')

def maybe_floor_int(n, epsilon=0.00000001):
    if abs(int(n) - n) < epsilon:
        return int(n)
    else:
        return n

def create_point(*args: 'tuple or pair of args') -> Point:
    """Make an int named pair (Point)"""

    if len(args) == 1:
        x, y = args
    else:
        x, y = args[0]

    return Point(maybe_floor_int(x), maybe_floor_int(y))
```

Since your `point` function is creating an instance of a `Point` tuple and you may eventually want to override `point`'s operators (like being able to scale them with multiplication), you may as well just create a dedicated `Point` class.